# MPMoviePlayerController interrupting playing audio

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app that can play online videos and
I want to play an ad first when the video data is loading.
First, I request an AdColony video Ad and begin to play it, then use `MPMoviePlayerController` to load video data, But when the video is prepared to play, it interrupts the previous Ad sound, and causes the ad to stop.

Here are the codes Im using:

```
// Play Ad first
[AdColony playVideoAdForSlot:1 withDelegate:self]; // It also use MPMoviePlayerController to play video

// Load video for playing
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
               init];
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,44,320,320);
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay]; // Interrupt Ad playing
```

The offical doc said "calling `prepareToPlay` may interrupt the movie player’s audio session", so the Ad was interrupted. If I remove `prepareToPlay`, the video data will not be preloaded
I have tried to put 
`[AdColony playVideoAdForSlot:1 withDelegate:self];` below `[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];`

but it does not work. Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: I've never used AdColony before, but do they provide you with a completion handler, adFinishedPlaying delegate, or anything like that?

Comment: The Ad video was interrupted, no handler for that

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to handle interruptions,

read through he Apples guide

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW1